# How to call google cloud shell from Postman or different browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I created a node.js sever inside the cloud shell. I can open the `Web Preview` and it will send a `GET` request to my server, but I also want to send a `POST` request to the server. If I try to call the same USL provided in `Web Preview` from anywhere outside of the current broswer which I am looged in with my google cloud, I will be redirected to login page.

Is there a way to `Authenticate` to google cloud by adding hedears in an API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a token so that you can authenticate to google cloud follow the below steps:

1. Login to Google Cloud Console
2. In API & Services -> Credentials create an OAuth 2.0 client ID
3. Authorize the redirect URL
4. Login to Postman client/browser app
5. Use the settings mentioned in the [document](https://pnatraj.medium.com/google-cloud-api-with-postman-f4cf070e665f) in the postman.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a follow up question. Does it need to be under an specific project? How to find out with project?

Comment: Yes ,it needs to be under a specific project.

Comment: The Cloud Shell I am working on is not under a project, or I can't find if it is. How can I find out which project or it just doesn't matter?

Comment: Try running these commands in a cloud shell :  
                                                            
1. `gcloud auth list`- You can list the active account name.
 
2. `gcloud config list project`- You can list the project ID. 

3. `gcloud config set <project-id>`- You can set project id.