# Postman request to Google Cloud Shell Editor Preview returns HTML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, postman, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I am writing a golang webserver with the Google Cloud Shell Editor and attempting to test it via postman by making requests against the URL generated when I create the web preview of my code running on port 8080. However instead of receiving a JSON response as expected I am receiving this HTML page.

**Request**: POST `https://8080-cs-277337641258-default.cs-us-east1-rtep.cloudshell.dev/api/userToken`

**Response**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <base href="https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/">
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
.
. (response too long to copy here)
.
</script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have successfully been able to generate my own authorization token referencing various stackoverflow posts and other websites such as:

- [How to call google cloud shell from Postman or different browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74568136/how-to-call-google-cloud-shell-from-postman-or-different-browser)
- [Using Postman to access OAuth 2.0 Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076503/using-postman-to-access-oauth-2-0-google-apis)

[API Credentials Client ID for Web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZRyE.png)

[Postman Authorization Token Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkBGJ.png)

[Token Created in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtdv9.png)

However despite this it looks like I'm still being prompted to authenticate my API request via the browser judging by the HTML response returned. Am I missing something or is a request like this via Postman to the Google Cloud Shell just not possible?